# template for rotate and right aligned text in a 2 columns horizontally shared page

Tags: align, templates, rotating, text

I'd like to share my page in 4 areas: A, B, C, D
page is half share horizontally and each of this areas are shared in half vertically .

A in the top left where text rotate of 180° and is aligns on the right margin
B in the top right where text rotate of 180°and is aligns on the right margin
C in the bottom left where text are normaly and is aligns on the left margin
C in the bottom right where text are normaly and is aligns on the left margin

I'd like to make a template that make my text "flow" in area A, B, C then D.

I'd prefer to avoid the use of a table but if it's the easier way, I'm not against.

here is the code I have made, it rotate text but text a left aligned and fail to make 2 columns

```
\documentclass{article}

% preambule
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[french]{babel}


\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\begin{multicols}{2}
\rotatebox{180}{coffe}
\newline
\rotatebox{180}{beer}
\newline
\rotatebox{180}{water} 
\newline
\rotatebox{180}{soda}
\newline
\rotatebox{180}{tea}
\newline
\rotatebox{180}{gin}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

here a pic to show what i want. Sharing lines may optionally be display or hidden. and part A and B can be tab instead of 2 columns, and if part A can't contain all the tab, it will continue in B part (Part A still reversed and part B normal.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. In any case, to have two columns, you have to add in the preambule the line \usepackage{multicol}.

Comment: maybe, this post can help you https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637844/make-text-flow-across-different-tikz-nodes/637873#637873

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

With expl3, 2 keys:

1. nbrows (4 by default)
2. angle (0° by defaut)

with tabularray

1. comment hlines,vlines, if if not delineated
2. colspec={*{2}{Q[l,m,wd=0.45\linewidth]}}, for the width of the column
3. rows = {0.1\textheight} for the height of the rows

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{showframe}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage{tabularray}
   \parindent=0pt
   \ExplSyntaxOn
   \seq_new:N \l__nameyourmodule_elem_seq
   \tl_new:N \l__nameyourmodule_table_tl
   \tl_new:N \l__nameyourmodule_nbrows_tl
   \tl_new:N \l__nameyourmodule_angle_tl
   \tl_new:N \l__nameyourmodule_rowHeight_tl
   \keys_define:nn { yourtable }
       { 
           nbrows .tl_set:N = \l__nameyourmodule_nbrows_tl,
           angle .tl_set:N = \l__nameyourmodule_angle_tl,
           %%% default values 
           nbrows .initial:n = { 4 },
           angle .initial:n = { 0 },
       }
   \NewDocumentCommand{\mytable}{O{} m }
   {
       \keys_set:nn { yourtable } { #1 }
       \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__nameyourmodule_elem_seq {#2}
       \tl_clear:N \l__nameyourmodule_table_tl
       \int_step_inline:nn {\l__nameyourmodule_nbrows_tl}
       % \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__nameyourmodule_elem_seq  
       {  
       \tl_put_right:Nn \l__nameyourmodule_table_tl 
           {
           \seq_item:Nn \l__nameyourmodule_elem_seq {##1} & 
           \seq_item:Nn \l__nameyourmodule_elem_seq {\l__nameyourmodule_nbrows_tl+##1}\\
           }
       }

       \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node[rotate=\l__nameyourmodule_angle_tl]
           {
           \use:x% code of frougon  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648904/misplaced-alignment-tab-character-with-tabularray-and-expl3
               {
               \exp_not:n {\begin{tblr}
                               {
                               hlines,vlines,
                               colspec={*{2}{Q[l,m,wd=0.45\linewidth]}},
                               rows = {0.1\textheight}
                               }}
               \exp_not:V {\l__nameyourmodule_table_tl}
               \exp_not:n {\end{tblr}}
               }
           };
       \end{tikzpicture}
   }
   \ExplSyntaxOff
   \begin{document}
   \mytable{Neqe,porro,quisquam,est,lg5}

   \mytable[angle=180]{Neqe,porro,quisquam,est,lg5}

   \mytable[nbrows=3]{lg1,lg2,lg3,lg4,lg5}

   \mytable[nbrows=3,angle=90]{lg1,lg2,lg3,lg4,lg5}
   \end{document}
   ```